# Null Pointer Exception when casting parent fragment to main Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a Main Fragment class that I have set up. In that Main Fragment, I have an ImageView with a onClick listener set up to it. Once that onClick is called, it then opens up a Dialog Fragment.

In my Dialog Fragment, I have a simple "Ok" or "Cancel" option set up inside it. Once the "Ok"
button is clicked, it's set up to cast the parent activity to the Main Fragment, and execute a method that is set up inside the Main Fragment called "onDialogOKPressed" so it will respond to the code that in inside that method only.

I have no errors inside my code, and can't seem to see where I would be getting "NullpointerException" once I click "Ok"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Main Fragments on click:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment,
            container, false);

    mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
            dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "MyDialogFragment");
        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

Dialog Fragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private Button ButtonOk;
private Button ButtonCancel;

public MyDialogFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt, container);
    ButtonOk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ButtonCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    getDialog().setTitle("Set Wallpaper?");

    ButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ((ImageDetailFragment) (MyDialogFragment.this
                    .getParentFragment())).onDialogOKPressed();

        }

    });

    ButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MyDialogFragment.this.dismiss();

        }
    });

    return view;

}
}
```

OnDialogOKPressed:

```
    public void onDialogOKPressed() {


    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView
            .getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();


    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 950, 1000, true);



    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(getActivity());

    try {

        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        ;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Wallpaper Successfully Set!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Setting Wallpaper",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at com.Question.ui.MyDialogFragment$1.onClick(MyDialogFragment.java:35)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4128)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17142)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
10-12 09:25:06.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line is `MyDialogFragment.java:35`?

Comment: Why are you casting your method this way ? ` ((ImageDetailFragment) (MyDialogFragment.this                 .getParentFragment())).onDialogOKPressed();` thought you can directly use it.

Answer (score 1):

`getParentFragment()` may be returning `null`.

According to [ParentFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29) documentation, this happens if the `DialogFragment` is attached to an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`.

Comment: No, it's attached to a Fragment.

Comment: Mmh can you debug step by step to evaluate `getParentFragment()` value? Is the only thing that makes to be throwing the `NPE`

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are going to do a callback after execute the onClick event on the popup window, am i understand correct? If so, you can just add a handler in the Main Fragment and send a message to the handler in onClick() method of Dialog Fragment.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set up it up so that when the "Ok" onClick is pressed. it somehow lets my main Fragment know that it had been clicked. Would there be an alternative way to do that from what I have already?

Comment: Could you give example of how to send a message to handler via onCLick in dialog Fragment? I have been trying to get this sorted for days now, and haven't managed to succeed...

Comment: Just added the example in the new reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();

public class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onDialogOKPressed()
    }
}


MyDialogFragment.myHandler.sendEmptyMessage();
```

if the static handler can not call onDialogOkPressed() for the non-static reference. you can just remove the static and try

```
new MyDialog().sendEmptyMessage();
```